# Get-ChildItem folders and filtering by name

Tags: powershell, file, copy, filtering

**Question**

I want to select all user folders that begin with the letter E in the users folder located in a computers c:\, and copy their desktop downloads and my documents to a server location, what am I missing in my below scripts?

**Details**

I work in an education environment and I am trying to create a script to make converting from local profiles on computers to folder redirection, I have to move many folders from the computers c:\users\username to a server location \\serverpath\username

I can manually copy desktop, download and documents folders to the respective locations but thought this would be perfect for a script.

I have written the following basic script

```
    $Computers = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "Redacted OU Location" -filter {name -like "ms*"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name

foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
    {$users = Get-ChildItem "\\$Computer\c$\users" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name
      foreach ($user in $users)
    {
        $Desktop = "\\$Computer\c$\users\$user\desktop"
        $Downloads = "\\$Computer\c$\users\$user\downloads"
        $Documents = "\\$Computer\c$\users\$user\documents"

        $ServerDesktop = "\\RedactedServerlocation\$user\desktop"
        $ServerDownloads = "\\RedactedServerlocation\$user\downloads"
        $ServerDocuments = "\\RedactedServerlocation\$user\documents"

    
    Copy-Item -Path $Desktop -Destination $ServerDesktop -Recurse
    Copy-Item -Path $Downloads -Destination $ServerDownloads -Recurse 
    copy-item -Path $Documents -Destination $ServerDocuments -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Recurse}
   }
```

The above script works ok and does what I am looking at doing, although I had to add the silently continue error handling as it wouldn't copy the "my music/videos/photos" folders found with in documents due to the below error

```
Copy-Item : Access to the path '\\RedactedComputername\c$\users\$RedactedUsername\documents\My Music' is denied.
At line:6 char:5
+     Copy-Item -Path "\\RedactedComputername\c$\users\$user\documents" -Dest ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (My Music:DirectoryInfo) [Copy-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CopyDirectoryInfoItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

I tried to set up an exclude with

```
$exclude = "$Documents\my music", "$documents\my pictures", "$documents\my videos"
Copy-Item -exclude $exclude -path $Documents -Destination $ServerDocuments -Recurse
```

But got the following error still, so I decided to ignore the error output as I decided this is an acceptable error, as it would be rare that these folders would get used in our environment and if people complained they were missing I could manually follow up with copying them to the server to provide access again

```
Copy-Item : Access to the path '\\RedactedComputername\c$\users\$user\Documents\My Music' is denied.
At line:16 char:5
+     Copy-Item -exclude $exclude -path $Documents -Destination $Server ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (My Music:DirectoryInfo) [Copy-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CopyDirectoryInfoItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

However I am looking at only choosing specific usernames contained with in the users folder to do this with. The username structure we have here is staff start with an E and have numbers after it. And students have their first and last names as the usernames.

I have tried using

```
$users = Get-ChildItem "\\$Computer\c$\users" -Filter {name -like "e*"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name
```

Thinking that if I can selectively grab all usernames beginning with E and move only them, then the clean up afterwards will be much easier but my filter option doesn't seem to work.

I get the following error in powershell when I try and filter the names that start with e with the above command

```
Get-ChildItem : Illegal characters in path.
At line:4 char:15
+ ...   {$users = Get-ChildItem "\\$Computer\c$\users" -Filter {name -like  ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (\\MS3C7C3F1E4AF9\c$\users:String) [Get-ChildItem], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

I have tried to find other solutions to what I am trying to do but I either don't understand them or I can't copy them and edit them to do what I want. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: tldr: I quess you need the escape the second  `$` sign for `C$`: ``Get-ChildItem "\\$Computer\c`$\users"``

Comment: No, my question was placed at the top but I will rephrase...
I dont want to select ALL folders in the users directory on the C:\users\ I only want to select the ones that start with the letter E

Comment: I indeed meant: ``...Get-ChildItem "\\$Computer\c`$\users" -Filter {name -like "e*"} |...`` (look to the details of the last error `InvalidArgument: (\\MS3C7C3F1E4AF9\c$\users:String)` which has `:String` added, this happens as it tries to expand the string after the `c$`)

Comment: My apologies, I just tried to run that with that escape character between the c and the $ sign and I got the same error. I also tried to copy and paste your comment into it just incase I saw the escape character as something different and i got the same error

Comment: It is actually: ``Get-ChildItem "\\$Computer\c`$\users" -Filter "e*"`` or  ``Get-ChildItem "\\$Computer\c`$\users" |Where-Object name -like "p*"``

Comment: Thanks for the help iRon, I have put it in as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help iRon, I changed that part of the script too the below, i tried putting the where-object at the end of the script and it was failing, I changed the order of the script block and put the where-object in the middle of it. This then filtered through all the names starting with "e" and moved only them.

`"$users = Get-ChildItem "\\$Computer\c$\users" | Where-Object name -like "e*" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name"`